# NumPy indexing using List?

Tags: python, numpy

SOF,

I noticed an interesting NumPy demo in this URL:

http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/

I see this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

# An example of integer array indexing.
# The returned array will have shape (3,) and 

print( a[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0]] )
# Prints "[1 4 5]"
```

I understand using integers as index arguments:

```
a[1,1]
```

and this syntax:

```
a[0:2,:]
```

Generally,
If I use a list as index syntax, what does that mean?

Specifically,
I do not understand why:

```
print( a[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0]] )
# Prints "[1 4 5]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last statement will print (in matrix notation) `a(0,0)`, `a(1,1)` and `a(2,0)`. In python notation that's `a[0][0]`, `a[1][1]` and `a[2][0]`.

The first index list contains the indices for the first axis (matrix notation: row index), the second list contains the indices for the second axis (column index).