# Unexpected behaviour when indexing a 2D np.array with two boolean arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

```
two_d = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
                  [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
                  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

first = np.array((True, True, False, False, False))
second = np.array((False, False, False, True, True))
```

Now, when I enter:

```
two_d[first, second]
```

I get:

```
array([3,9])
```

which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Can anybody explain that simply?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When given multiple boolean arrays to index with, NumPy pairs up the indices of the True values. The first true value in `first` in paired with the first true value in `second`, and so on. NumPy then fetches the elements at each of these (x, y) indices.

This means that `two_d[first, second]` is equivalent to:

```
two_d[[0, 1], [3, 4]]
```

In other words you're retrieving the values at index (0, 3) and index (1, 4); `3` and `9`. Note that if the two arrays had different numbers of true values an error would be raised!

The [documents on advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) mention this behaviour briefly and suggest `np.ix_` as a 'less surprising' alternative:

> Combining multiple Boolean indexing arrays or a Boolean with an integer indexing array can best be understood with the `obj.nonzero()` analogy. The function `ix_` also supports boolean arrays and will work without any surprises.

Hence you may be looking for:

```
>>> two_d[np.ix_(first, second)]
array([[3, 4],
       [8, 9]])
```

Comment: to get what i assume you wanted to get, you can use

    two_d[first].T[second].T

Comment: @pixelbrei: yes that could work here, although the docs suggest using `np.ix_` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [documentation on boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

`two_d[first, second]` is the same as
 `two_d[first.nonzero(), second.nonzero()]`, where:

```
>>> first.nonzero()
(array([0, 1]),)
>>> second.nonzero()
(array([3, 4]),)
```

Used as indices, this will select 3 and 9 because

```
>>> two_d[0,3]
3
>>> two_d[1,4]
9
```

and

```
>>> two_d[[0,1],[3,4]]
array([3, 9])
```

Also mildy related: [NumPy indexing using List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716376/numpy-indexing-using-list)